# How to properly parse an array of Fetch responses

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, fetch-api

In trying to implement functionality to enable users to make partial updates to some data, I have come up with the following logical operations:

1. Fetch and load data fields on a form.
2. The user makes edits to some editable fields and hits save
3. Check to see if fields have actually changed then map out fields to update
4. Build an array of fetch promises (one for each editable field: the API endpoint for `PATCH`ing each editable field is distinct)
5. Using `Promise.all`, get an array of responses (promises)
6. Parse the array of responses to get data I am interested in.

The following is how I have actually implemented the above:

```
 /*   EDIT RECORD
  * @param path: path to the record (ex: '/record/2')
  * @param fields: object containing fields to update (ex: { comment: "new comment here" })
  */
   async editRecord(path, fields) {
     const responsePromises = await Promise.all(
       Object.keys(fields).map(field =>                 // create an array of a number of fetch requests detemined by number of fields
         this.patchRecord(path, field, fields[field])      // returns a fetch request
       )
     ).then(res => res.map(each => each.json()));       // return  an array of "json decoded"?? response promises  


  /*
   * For each response promise:
   *  1. Grab a message or an errorlist
   *  2. Append the message, or list of errors to an object holding the errors/messages of already parsed responses
   */
    const { errors, messages } = await responsePromises.reduce(
      async (parsedObjectPromise, response) => {
        const parsedObject = await parsedObjectPromise;
        const { data, errors: responseErrors } = await response;
        let message;

        if (data) [message] = data;

        if (responseErrors) parsedObject.errors.push(...responseErrors);
        if (message) parsedObject.messages.push(message);

        return parsedObject;
      },
      { errors: [], messages: [] }
    );

    console.log(errors, messages);
  },




  /*
   *  Returns a fetch request for one datafield update
   * @param path: path to the record (ex: '/record/2')
   * @param field: field to update (ex: 'comment')
   * @param value: value to update field with  (ex: 'new comment')
   */   

  patchRecord(path, field, value) {
    let requestUrl = IR_HELPERS.buildFetchPath({ singleRecordPath: path });
    requestUrl += `/${field}`;   // ex: 127.0.0.1:2343/record/2/comment

    return fetch(requestUrl, {
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${IR_HELPERS.token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ [field]: value }),
    });
  },
```

This works fine but for clarity's sake:

1. Is this approach sound or is there a better way to implement the above?
2. How can I combine the two distinct steps in the `editRecord` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good, if there were anything to move, it'd be the `responsePromises.reduce`, up into the `then` block, or have that one return the mapped responses into a new `then` block.

```js
/*   EDIT RECORD
  * @param path: path to the record (ex: '/record/2')
  * @param fields: object containing fields to update (ex: { comment: "new comment here" })
  */
async editRecord(path, fields) {
  Promise.all(
    Object.keys(fields).map(field => 
      this.patchRecord(path, field, fields[field]))
  )
  .then(res => res.map(each => each.json()))
    /*
     * For each response promise:
     *  1. Grab a message or an errorlist
     *  2. Append the message, or list of errors to an object holding the errors/messages of already parsed responses
     */
  .then(responsePromises => responsePromises.reduce(
    async (parsedObjectPromise, response) => {
      const parsedObject = await parsedObjectPromise;
      const { data, errors: responseErrors } = await response;
      let message;

      if (data) [message] = data;

      if (responseErrors) parsedObject.errors.push(...responseErrors);
      if (message) parsedObject.messages.push(message);

      return parsedObject;
    },
    { errors: [], messages: [] }
  ))
  .then(({ errors, messages }) => {
    console.log(errors, messages);
  });       
}
```